# How can I reset render cache on an entity for current user in hook_entity_view_alter()?

Tags: 8, commerce, caching

I have Commerce products for which I'm showing or hiding the add-to-cart link, if that product is or isn't in the current cart.  In my code:

```
function mymodule_commerce_product_view_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
    $myservice = \Drupal::service('myservice');
    if ($myservice->isProductInCurrentCart($entity->id()) {
        $build['add_to_cart_link']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

That works fine, however, when the product entities are rendered, they retain their cache and will continue to display, or not display, the add-to-cart link until the cache is cleared.

In my view_alter hook, how can I clear the cache for the current user for that entity before it's rendered?  Can I set a cache tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I disabled the cache for the link, but the entity was cached, preventing the link from being shown or hidden.  Therefore, I disabled the cache for the entity and that worked.

In the alter hook:

```
$build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0
```

The entity is now rendered with the proper state of the cart link.